# Dojo Evented - "load" event is not fired/caught

Tags: javascript, events, dojo

I have a class that inherits [dojo/Evented](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/Evented.html). I call the `myClass.emit("load",{})` in my code. and listen to it by `myClassInstance.on("load",function(){console.log("fired!")});`

However, it's not fired. But interestingly, if I change to `myClass.emit("myClass-load",{})` and listen by `myClassInstance.on("myClass-load",function(){console.log("fire")});` the event get fired!

What did I miss here? Is it because other objects also listen to "load" event so it's not caught by myClassInstance?

***Generally,*** what happens if two events, fired by two objects have the same name? Is it better to name each event uniquely?

Thanks,
Allen

Comment: Is your class only inheriting `dojo/Evented`, or is it actually a Dijit widget?  Widgets' treatment of `on` and `emit` is a bit less straightforward and might explain what you're experiencing.

Comment: @KenFranqueiro thanks for pointing out the difference! Yes, myClass also inherits the [dijit/_WidgetBase](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_WidgetBase.html). How does this make a difference on my code?

Comment: It'd really be helpful if you could show the code for the class having the problem (or something minimal that reproduces it).  I can think of one or two possible explanations.

Comment: @KenFranqueiro Sorry, I probably cannot show the code here since this is part of my internship.... Would you mind sharing with me about what speculations you have? Really want to appreciate your help! I will post answers here if I verify the cause later.

Answer (score 1):

If your class is inheriting `dijit/_WidgetBase`, there are a couple of differences in its treatment of `on` and `emit` that I might suspect are causing your issue.

Firstly, _WidgetBase [won't emit DOM events](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/1.10.4/_WidgetBase.js#L932) before the widget has `startup` called or after/while it is destroyed.  In other words, it won't emit DOM events during its `constructor`, `postscript`, `buildRendering`, and `postCreate`.

Secondly, _WidgetBase contains some admittedly convoluted logic for backwards compatibility with legacy widgets which implement events via methods following the `onXxx` naming pattern.  While `_WidgetBase#emit` will still fire a DOM event even if a matching `onXxx` method exists, [`_WidgetBase#on` will *not* listen for the DOM event](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/1.10.4/_WidgetBase.js#L952-L957) if it finds an `onXxx` method first.

Therefore, I'd suggest making sure of 2 things:

- `emit` isn't being called on the widget prior to `startup`
- The widget doesn't already have an `onLoad` method

I suppose one final thing I should point out is that you shouldn't make a class inherit *both* `_WidgetBase` and `Evented`, as this may cause unintended side effects in widget logic, especially if you're extending an existing Dijit widget.  Extending `_WidgetBase` alone should suffice since it already defines its own `emit` and `on` (linked above).

Comment: Thanks very much Ken! I will review the code based on your suggestions and post what I find here!